# Mathematical control and differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

The differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}= Ax(t)+ Bu(t)+ f(t,x(t))+ g(t,u(t))$$ subjected to $x(0)=a$ defined on $[0, t], t>0$, where $u$ is a control and $x$ is a state. Does this differential equation make any sense?

Comment: Such a differential equation *could* make sense, with information about the (known?) functions $u,f,g$ and constants(?) $A,B$, with the initial condition $x=a$ at time $t=0$.  But without that *context* there isn't much mathematical reasoning that can be done about "Does this differential equation make any sense?".

Comment: Yes, this differential equation makes sense.

Comment: Well , you need to impose conditions on $f$ in order to ensure existence and uniqueness of the solutions.

Comment: For "reasonable" $u$ and fairly "nice" $f$, your equation has a unique solution, so that control-theoretic problems with it can be studied.